# What is the "xxx: script" syntax in perl?

Tags: perl

I have a script like this, and it runs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
error: print 0x41
```

I'm expecting the `error:` part to trigger an syntax error, but it didn't. Does anyone know this syntax?

Comment: In this context `error:` is a label which can be utilized with [goto](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_goto.htm), [next](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next), [continue](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/continue), [last](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last), [redo](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/redo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a label.

For example,

```perl
OUTER:
for my $x (qw( a b c )) {
   for my $y (1..3) {
      say "$x$y";
      last OUTER if $x eq 'b';
   }
}
```

Output:

```
a1
a2
a3
b1
```